# What's equivalent to "font-size-adjust"?

Tags: css, web, fonts, font-size

I want to specify two different fonts in a font-family (`font-family:A, B;`) but the sizes of these two fonts are different.

It seems `font-size-adjust` onlys work in Firefox. So how can I adjust second font size if the first one is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The conclusion is that you should list only fonts that are sufficiently similar in their properties.

Well, there are some tricks used to detect the availability of a font on the basis of its properties. You could use font A (only) for an invisible inline test element containing some text and then compare, using JavaScript, the width of the test element with its measured width (allowing some small difference, since different implementations of font A may yield slightly different widths). If the widths don’t match, you would change the font size setting for the element(s) that have `font-family: A, B`, so that the size is suitable for B. Well, you would still have the problem that font B might not be available either. So it would be messy, with no real guarantee of success.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `font-size-adjust` isn't standard, and is hence won't work.

I think that the best way to solve your problem isn't to try and work around two completely different font sizes, but to select two fonts that are sufficiently similar as so the sizing is consistent.

Preferably, I would use [Web Fonts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) (Also, http://www.google.com/fonts is a good place to start), so ensure that everyone gets the same experience, and you can load consistent, beautiful fonts across browsers and platforms. If the performance hit is a problem, then consider using [reliable font stacks](http://www.cssfontstack.com/).

I understand that this isn't a strict answer to your question, but it may be a better way to go. :)